# dictionary for tableView datasource

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

I am trying to use a dictionary for a tableView datasource, I am getting an object back from the database that contains a key and an array of values, so a [String: [String]]

```
    var requestedList = [String]()
    var keyArr = [String]()
    var requestedDictionary = [String: [String]]()

    let tQuery = PFQuery(className: "MyClass")
        tQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.username as Any)
        tQuery.selectKeys(["descContent", "header"])
        do {
            let returnedObjects = try tQuery.findObjects()
            for object in returnedObjects {
                let header = object["header"] as! String
                keyArr.append(header)
                if let arr = object["descContent"] as! [String]? {
                    requestedDictionary[header] = arr
                    requestedList += arr
                }
            }
        } catch {
        }
```

I can't seem to correspond the values correctly to the rows of the tableView however, I was suggested to use an array to store the values which is what I have done with the keyArr. My problem is how do I access the contents of the keys and the corresponding values in the datasource methods?? This is what I have so far but I haven't been able to link the keys and values accordingly

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return requestedList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RequestViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RequestViewCell

        cell.descLbl.text = "Your ticket has been requested by \(requestedList[indexPath.row])"
        cell.refLbl.text = "for: \(keyArr[indexPath.row])"

        cell.leftBtn.tag = (indexPath.section * 100) + indexPath.row
        cell.leftBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(leftClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.rightBtn.tag = (indexPath.section * 100) + indexPath.row
        cell.rightBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rightClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why a dictionary in this case? I can't think of any reason to use a dictionary as a table view data source. That seems really weird to me.

Comment: what values do you want in the rows of your table? I.e. should there be one row per PFObject, or one row for each string in the `descContent` arrays?  Also, adding an action handler in `cellForRowAt` won't work as cells are reused and you will get duplicate handlers registered. Better to have the cell handle the button actions and invoke a delegate function or closure. That way you can avoid the issue of tag values too

Comment: @CharlieFish I am using a dictionary because the data that I have stored are related. Its something like multiple users are making a request to the same thing and only one can be used for a given task.

Comment: @Paulw11 there should be one row for each string in the descContent

Comment: So you have a problem; you are going to have fewer elements in your `keyArr` array. You need to rethink how you want to layout your data. Perhaps use multiple sections in your tableview?

Comment: @Paulw11 is there a way I can assign the keys with the values through custom cell elements like textfields so that way I can have the same amount?...

Comment: Possibly. It depends on what you want it to look like. You could have the descContent strings as a comma separated list in a single label.

Comment: i was thinking if I had 2 values associated with 1 key, I would create some collection object that would copy the key so that it contains the same amount of elements as the values and then push them back into a dictionary so that each key has a singular value

Comment: @dpat0074 I'd really think about your data structure here. It seems wildly ineffective for what you want. The things you outlined aren't enough reasons to use a poor data type here.

Comment: @CharlieFish Do you have any recommendations as to alternative structure. My goal is to assign a task only to one person where many people can request it.

Comment: You already have an array returned from `findObjects`. I think you are making things harder for yourself by creating a dictionary.

Comment: @dpat0074 I don't totally understand your end goal and what you need here. But normally for a table you have just an array of elements. Sometimes a 2d array for sections. But I'd have to see some examples of your data in order to help give recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn **dictionary** into **tableView representable data** this way.

```
let requestedDictionary:[String: [String]] = [
    "Key-1":["Value-1","Value-2","Value-3","Value-4"],
    "Key-A":["Value-X","Value-Y","Value-Z"],
    "Key-a":["Value-x","Value-y"],
]
lazy var data:[(key:String,values:[String])] = requestedDictionary.compactMap({(key:$0,values:$1)})

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data[section].values.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.section].values[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return data[section].key
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works and solves my issue. You can also create a struct to take in the data types. Thanks!!